# passing data while navigation between pages onNavigatedTo no suitable method found to override in Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation, parameter-passing, overriding

I'm try to pass a parameter while navigate between pages..
in the firs page I have:

```
private void companyGrid_Tap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        String tempVal = "";
        tempVal = "PassVal";
        NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/ComPage.xaml?comID=" + tempVal, UriKind.Relative));
    }
```

and in the next page i have:

```
protected override void onNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
        String strId = NavigationContext.QueryString["comID"];

    }
```

but I get an error about the override "onNavigatedTo" mathod say: "no suitable method found to override"

i check and all the Examples show the same way to pass the parameter... 
Maybe someone know what the reason it's not working???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not at my desktop at the moment so not 100% sure, but shouldn't it be OnNavigatedTo (capital O at the start)?

So you'd have:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    String strId = NavigationContext.QueryString["comID"];
}
```