# Variable Transfer between screens on Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

I'm new at application developing on Windows Phone 8.

Here is my question:

I'm trying to transfer a variable between screens.

In details, i have a score variable on game screen. I want to transfer this score variable on sendscore.xaml page.

I hope you all can understand me. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If (what I think) you mean screen == page then there are a lot of examples and tutorials: [one](http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-alternatives), [two](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/balsharfi/archive/2013/01/16/starting-windows-phone-development-lesson-3-of-n-navigation-between-pages-and-passing-parameters.aspx), [three](http://nishantcop.blogspot.com/2011/08/passing-data-between-pages-in-windows.html)
And a lot more if you try to search.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this blog post: [#WPDev Tips: How to pass an object to WP Navigation Service?](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2013/10/passing-object-to-wp-navigation-service.html)

Create a helper class.

```
public static class Extensions
{
    private static object Data;

    public static void Navigate(this NavigationService navigationService, 
                                Uri source, object data)
    {
        Data = data;
        navigationService.Navigate(source);
    }

    public static object GetNavigationData(this NavigationService service)
    {
        return Data;
    }
}
```

In Page1.xaml.cs, let's say a button click event has this body.

```
var objPerson = new Person { FirstName = "Farhan", LastName = "Ghumra" };
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Page2/xaml", UriKind.Relative), objPerson);
```

In Page2.xaml.cs's OnNavigatedTo event or constructor

```
var objPerson = (Person)NavigationService.GetNavigationData();
```

Answer (score 1):

So when you navigate you use this code:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Chatting.xaml?SelectedIndex="+selectedItemID.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));
```

And you override onNavigatedTo and insert

```
            selectedItemID = Convert.ToInt32(this.NavigationContext.QueryString["SelectedIndex"]);
```

Comment: I've tried to do this like this:
on gamepage.xaml:
(tiklama_sayac is what I've been trying to transfer)
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/GamePage2.xaml?Puan=" + tiklama_sayac.ToString(), UriKind.Relative));

on gamepage2.xaml.cs:
int aldigi_puan;
        aldigi_puan = Convert.ToInt32(this.NavigationContext.QueryString["Puan"]);

but it returns this error: aldigi_puan is a field but used like a type. What I have to do?

Comment: I haven't know how to override so this help me a lot: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11014774/1754573

Comment: @BerkayTutal Hope it helps a vote up an answer allways is nice :)

Comment: I've tried to vote up but I don't have enough reputation to vote :)

Comment: @BerkayTutal You can vote my question or mark it as answer now, with your reputation? :)